# handles are getting deleted

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have 3 row-vectors, and would like to output them out of my GUI, if I close it.

First I tried it with global variables in the GUI, which i access and put them in the output function:

```
global horizontalFrames;
global verticalFrames;
global blackFrames;

varargout{1} = horizontalFrames;
varargout{2} = verticalFrames;
varargout{3} = blackFrames;
```

But, all values are ALREADY AT THIS POINT zero, even if i set them in the code.
Why are they set zero?

Then I tried it by the use of handles like this:

```
handles.horizontalFrames = horizontalFrames;
handles.verticalFrames = verticalFrames;
handles.blackFrames = blackFrames;
```

somewhere in the code (where the values are NOT all zero)
and then write this in the output function:

```
varargout{1} = handles.horizontalFrames
varargout{2} = handles.verticalFrames
varargout{3} = handles.blackFrames
```

the handles cant be found. It seems, like the handles are not accessible from the output function, or they are deleted. I'm desperate... where is my data, why can't I simply output it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out. I had to update my handles with

```
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

"somewhere in the code" again, means, immediately after adding my variables.

Greets, hope it helps someone.